# Why does an object returning itself as the default property hang excel and crash the debugger?

Tags: excel, vba, class, default

I recently came accross `Attribute Values.VB_UserMemId = 0'. I like lists so I thought I'd build a bespoke collection type object.

The minimal code for the class that can reproduce the error is:

**Class `Lst`**

```
Option Explicit

Public c As New Collection

'this is the default property
Public Property Get item(Optional index)
'Attribute Values.VB_UserMemId = 0
    If IsMissing(index) Then
        Set item = Me
        'DoEvents
    Else
        item = c(index)
    End If
End Property

Public Property Let item(Optional index, itm)
    If IsMissing(index) Then 'assume itm is list
        If IsObject(itm) Then Set c = itm.c Else c.add itm
    Else
        c.add itm, , index
        c.Remove index + 1
    End If
End Property
```

Essentially, `lst(i)` returns the ith element of the private collection, `Lst(i)=6` sets the ith element. (errorhandling and index checking code stripped for clarity).

I noticed that objects that return themselves from the default property can be returned from a function in a variant (e.g `LstFunc=L` below), without the need for a `set` removing complexity from my students eyes...(you cant do that with a collection object)

Unfortunately, I encountered two challenges...the minimum code for these is:

**The Problem**

```
Function LstFunc() As Variant
    Dim L As New Lst
    L = 4 'replaces L.item=3
    LstFunc = L 'this is not normally allowed, but desirable (for me!)
End Function

Sub try()
    Dim L As New Lst
    L = LstFunc 'replaces L.item=LstFunc-->L.c: [4]
    L = 3 'L.c: [4,3]
    If L = 6 Then DoEvents
End Sub
```

Here is what happens

1) when the expression `L = 6` is evaluated excel hangs. Some times `ESC` gets you it back in, but my experience is that excel stops responding and needs a restart.

To evaluate the expression the L.item function is called initially, returning a `Lst`, for which item is called, etc.etc. resulting in unwanted, and undetected infinite repetition (not quite recursion). Uncommenting the `DoEvents` statement in the get item property allows you to stop without a crash

2) after uncommenting the `DoEvents`, I run in debugger mode step by step. If i now hover (by accident..) over the variable L, the debugger crashes, and I get the *green triangle of death*, which I fear will be very confusing for the students:
[image: green triangle of death...]

Note this behaviour is recoverable if the `DoEvents` statement in the class is commented out again. A veritable catch 22...

Bit of an intricate one this, but any sugesstions as to how I can trap the unwanted repetition in (1) at low computational cost and without losing the ability to pass the object like a variant would be greatfully received.

PS this is a code snipped that provides an unsafe workaround discussed in a comment below:

```
Public Property Get item(Optional index)
'Attribute Values.VB_UserMemId = 0
    static i
    If IsMissing(index) Then
        Set item = Me
        i=i+1:if i>1000 then item="":exit property
        'DoEvents
    Else
        item = c(index)
        i=0
    End If
End Property
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "trap the unwanted recursion". Also, I'm not clear on what the purpose of having an object return itself from the default method is. You ***always*** have the ability to "pass the object like a variant" in that anything can be stored in a Variant.

Comment: Probably should have used 'unintended' infinite repetition caused by evaluation of the p=6 statement as technically it calls  L.item repeatedly rather than recursively

Comment: Re the 'returning itself' this is quite distinctly different, note in the code above I work with objects and can treat them as variants, SET is not used at all. you can't return a collection from a function without using Set; one thing less for the students unfamiliar with VBA to get wrong.

Answer (score 2):

The recursion can't be avoided.

From section [5.6.2.2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee200207.aspx) of the VBA language specification:

> - If the expression’s value type is a specific class:
>
>   - If the source object has a public default **Property Get** or a public default function, and this default member’s parameter list is
>       compatible with an argument list containing 0 parameters, the simple
>       data value’s value is the result of evaluating this default member as
>       a simple data value.

Note that with your sample class, this line of code meets all of those conditions:

> ```
> If L = 6 Then DoEvents
> ```

The type of the expression `L = 6` is Boolean, with an `Lst` on the left hand side and an `Integer` on the right hand side. That means the type of the comparison is `Integer`, so the run-time checks to see if there is a default `Property Get`, which you provide here:

> ```
> Public Property Get item(Optional index)
> 'Attribute Values.VB_UserMemId = 0
> ```

The parameter list is compatible with an argument list containing 0 parameters, because the `index` is optional. So, it evaluates to `L.item() = 6`.  The only test you do inside the property is `If IsMissing(index)`, which is ***guaranteed to be true if it's called as the default member*** - remember, it ***can't*** require a parameter to be passed. As you found out, this leads you to...

> **[5.6.2.3](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee199845.aspx) Default Member Recursion Limits**
>
> Evaluation of an object whose default **Property Get** or default function
>   returns another object can lead to a recursive evaluation process if
>   the returned object has a further default member. Recursion through
>   this chain of *default members* may be implicit if evaluating to a
>   simple data value and each default member has an empty parameter list,
>   or explicit if index expressions are specified that specifically
>   parameterize each default member.

How this is handled is implementation specific. Office VBA implementations, however, do not cap the recursion depth and will simply crash the host when it runs out of stack space.

---

That said, the rest of your question is simply an [x-y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), although my suggestion is to scrap this. Using default members hides the intent of your code and robust, maintainable code should be readable.

Comment: I haven't looked at OP's code in details, but I believe such a recursive default member implementation can also crash the *locals* debugger toolwindow.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon I'm guessing that it would - I haven't loaded up the OP's class in the VBE, but I'd be surprised if it didn't exhibit the same behavior as hovering over the variable in the debugger.

Comment: @above two gents, much appreciated you response time! Note the behaviour is different, and depends on whether the doevent statement is uncommented or not.

Comment: I now do have a 'solution', I added a static counter to the get item property, and return a string if the counter goes over 1000; counter is set to zero if an index was provided to reset. So as long as L(1) is called once in every 999 L() calls, it will work. Note this will fail if we add 1001 items to the list.... something better would be nice!

Comment: @comintern I looked at what is mend by XY-problem :-) agree there is an element of that, though the response of the debugger to the introduction of the Doevent statement has not been clarified.

Comment: @vbAdder I could try to replicate this locally with your code, but I'm not sure exactly what the point would be. The way that the host application fails in the presence of an infinitely recursive call chain is undefined, so I'm not sure what the purpose of attempting to describe what happens when you yield cycles to clear the Excel event queue is.

Comment: Agree, the recursion in the if then statement is clear now, and the actions of the vba debugger will be related to this. The subtleties of that, and the impact of calling doevents is probably beyond the scope of this forum as it depends on the debuggers implementation rather then vba. I will close the question; thx